# C++ assign by reference equivalent of PHP?

Tags: c++, reference

I am profiling an old legacy C++ application.

I saw there are lots of `vector<class>` var declared:

```
vector<someClass> myVec1;
vector<someClass> myVec2;
vector<someClass> myVec3;
```

This vector can grow quite a lot. In the code I also found that sometimes it is done:

```
myVec2 = myVec1;
```

This assign operation acutally makes a copy of data, and if the vector is pretty large the operation is slow.

Is there any way to assign to `myVec2` only a reference of `myVec1` without having to refactor all the code that relies on these variables (ie allocating them dynamically)?

Note that after the assignment `myVec1` is not used anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try `myVec2.swap(myVec1);`, which should be very fast. Since you don't care about `myVec1` any more, it doesn't matter that it now contains the original contents of `myVec2`.

Comment: *cool* I was thinking looking into std::move, but this is simpler.

Comment: `std::move` would probably make more sense, because there is no need to keep any data in `myVec1` any more.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any general other way to do this (if i don't have a .swap method) ? Consider that the code does some operation on both vectors (while they are not the same) before swapping them.

Answer (score 5):

You can declare a reference variable like this:

```
vector<someClass> myVec1;
vector<someClass>& myVec2 = myVec1;
```

However, if `myVec1` goes out of scope `myVec2` will be bad.
Also, if you are using a c++11 compiler your vector can be 'moved' instead of copied.

Hard to say what you need to do without knowing your use case.

Comment: I can't because the code does some operation on both vectors before eventually assigning them to each other

Answer (score 3):

If you do not need to reassign your vector variable you can use C++ reference like this:

```
vector<someClass> myVec1;
vector<someClass>& myVec2 =  myVec1;
```

(this works like assigning constant pointer to myVec2 but preserves semantic of "by-value" variable)

More about references in C++ and possible pitfalls [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references).

Comment: I can't because the code does some operation on both vectors before eventually assigning them to each other

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to?  If you want to reference `myVect1`, then reference it by the name `myVect1`.

Copying a vector is extremely useful:  it can be used as a snapshot or initialize another from one in a useful state.

Anyway, copying a few megabytes of data isn't all that slow anymore.  Milliseconds at worst.